# Animation that draws in real time

Tags: python, opencv, animation, draw, kdtree

I'm trying to create an animation that paints an image in real time (with Turtle) like this :

[image]

Here is the given image :

[image]

And here is the result (absolutely not the result wanted..)

[image]

Here is my code :

```
import cv2 as cv
import sys
import os.path
import turtle
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree


def draw_pixel(turtle, x, y, color) :
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.dot(1, color)
    return

def parseArray(array):
    parsedArray = []
    for i in array:
        for j in i:
            parsedArray.append((j[0][0], j[0][1]))
    return parsedArray

img = cv.imread(sys.argv[1])
height, width, channels = img.shape
canny = cv.Canny(img, 215, 275)
contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(canny,cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

parsedArray = parseArray(contours)
tree = KDTree(parsedArray)
dist, ind = tree.query([(0, 0)], k=len(parsedArray))
pixel = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)

for i in range(len(parsedArray)):
    x = int(parsedArray[int(ind[0][i])][0])
    y = int(parsedArray[int(ind[0][i])][1])
    draw_pixel(pixel, x, y, "black")
```

I retrieved all the contours of the given image with the `findContours` method, i parsed the contours list with all the contours positons and i did a kdtree at the positon [(0, 0)] to find all the nearest positon of it, and after i just loop through this list and draw each positions, but it doesn't give me the wanted result, so what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Please include the `import` statements so we can see what libraries are being used.

Comment: I have added the `import` statements !

Comment: Could you please give a link to a example data file, or attach such a file for us to test with?

Comment: You could add some debug output like printing len(parsedArray) or the x and y of a draw_pixel call.

Comment: What does pixel = turtle.Turtle(visible=False) do? Shouldnt it be visible = True?!!

Comment: The `visible=False` is to hide the turtle icon/pointer when drawing @Micka

Comment: Please, provide a sample input image, and elaborate on what exactly "doesn't paint at all the image given in parameters" means (ideally provide some examples and point out how that differs from expected result.)

Comment: I provided the image used on arguments, and an exemple of to understand the "doesn't paint at all the image given in parameters", with some explication of what am i doing on my code at the end, which obviously doesn't work... @DanMašek

Comment: I'm not convinced a KDTree is the right tool.  Just because two points are close together does not mean they are part of the same contour.  If I remove your KDTree stuff and just plot `parsedArray`, the image is recognizable (although upside down), although there are lots of crossing marks.

Comment: My goal is to have an animation that draw like a real person do, we don't we don't draw from top to bottom or bottom to top, but we tend to draw continuous lines and focus on a particular area before moving on to another. That's why I use kd-tree, because I would have to draw the pixels that are adjacent together first, then move to the next closest pixel so as to stay in the same region, etc ... as in the animation at the very top of my question @TimRoberts

Answer (score 1):

One of your big problems is that `.setposition` DRAWS the whole time it's moving to that position.  So, even when you're repositioning to the start of a new contour, you drag the pen.

What you get back from opencv is a set of contours, and you're going to want to keep those together.

Watch this one, which is much more satisfying:

```
import sys
import os.path
import turtle
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread(sys.argv[1])
height, width, channels = img.shape
canny = cv.Canny(img, 215, 275)
contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny,cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
pixel = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)

for contour in contours:
    pixel.penup()
    pixel.goto(*contour[0])
    pixel.pendown()
    for pt in contour[1:]:
         pixel.goto(*pt[0])
```

### Followup

I kind of expected you to use this as a basis for what you want, but here is a version that chooses the next contour by picking the one that has an endpoint closest to the one just drawn.  This actually looks for either endpoint, because most of the contours are small, but an exercise left to the reader is to draw the next contour in reverse order if we are actually closer to the other end.

```
import sys
import os.path
import turtle
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread(sys.argv[1])
canny = cv.Canny(img, 215, 275)
contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny,cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
pixel = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)

# Find closest contour.  We'll use Manhattan distance
# because it won't really matter.

def distance( a, b ):
    return abs(a[0]-b[0])+abs(a[1]-b[1])

def findClosest( contours, ept ):
    dist = []
    for c in contours:
        dist.append( distance( *c[0], ept ) )
        dist.append( distance( *c[-1], ept ) )

    return dist.index(min(dist)) // 2

# Draw in a forward direction.

def drawContour( ctr ):
    if len(ctr) == 1:
        return ctr[0][0]
    pixel.penup()
    pixel.goto(*ctr[0])
    pixel.pendown()
    for pt in ctr[1:]:
         pixel.goto(*pt[0])
    return pt[0]

nxt = drawContour( contours.pop(0) )
while contours:
    ndx = findClosest( contours, nxt )
    nxt = drawContour( contours.pop(ndx) )
```

### Followup #2

There are two ways to invert the drawing.  The easy way is just to invert the image matrix itself:

```
import numpy as np
...
img = np.flip( img, 0 )
```

Note that it costs you nothing to import numpy, because opencv has already imported it.

Alternatively, you can invert the Y coordinates of the contours themselves.  This is probably slightly more CPU-efficient, but it's not as intuitive.  Do this just after creating the contours:

```
ym = max( c[:,:,1].max() for c in contours )
for c in contours:
    c[:,:,1] = ym - c[:,:,1]
```

Comment: This is exactly the result I wanted, thank you very much! Personally, I definitely want to use kd-tree for this but I see you used Manhattan distance, what is the difference, is it faster in this case? And how to use kd-tree in particular with the same result? Thanks a lot ! @TimRoberts

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but how do I turn the drawing around so it's in the right place? @TimRoberts

Comment: Thanks for your last edit, i have a last question before i can close this question, why for some picture (bigger than the given one), the draw is not centered, and how can we always center the draw in the middle of the window ? Thanks again ! @TimRoberts

Comment: Print out the coordinates.  The turtle starts with (0,0) in the center, which will map to one corner of your image.  To center the image, you'll need to move the turtles starting position.